# How do I return my data from a function?

Tags: node.js, express, pg-promise

I've written a small database function that gets some data from the DB and puts it into the format that I want, but I'm having difficulties returning the data to display it with Express. The database function is as follows:

```
function getAllEvents(req, res, next) {
  db.any('select * from sensors, events where sensors.sensorid = events.sensorid')
    .then(function (data) {
        var final = [];

        data.forEach(function(datas){
            if (!final[datas.sensorid]){
                final[datas.sensorid] = {};
            }
            if (!final[datas.sensorid].name){
                final[datas.sensorid].name = datas.name;
                final[datas.sensorid].signatures = {};
            }
            if (!final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature]){
                final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature] = {};
                final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature].id = "sen" + datas.sensorid + "sig" + datas.signature;
                final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature].signature = datas.signature;
                final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature].message = datas.message;
                final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature].events = {};
            }

            final[datas.sensorid].signatures[datas.signature].events[datas.eventid] = datas;
        })

        return final;

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong! ", err)
    });
}
```

And the router function to call it is this:

```
router.get('/events', function(req, res, next) {
    db.getAllEvents(function(err, data){
        res.render('events', { data: data });
    });
});
```

I think the router function is waiting indefinitely for the data though as I get no errors but the page never loads. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

This code:

```
router.get('/events', function(req, res, next) {
    db.getAllEvents(function(err, data){
        res.render('events', { data: data });
    });
});
```

is ok besides the fact that you are not checking for errors. Notice that getAllEvents is expecting a function as an argument.

now Let's look at your getAllEvents function prototype

```
function getAllEvents(req, res, next) {
```

**It is simply not correct** and should have been something like

```
function getAllEvents(callback) {
```

Then you would be able to call the callback and "return" the result like this

```
return callback(null,data);
```

or if an error occurred during you database connection pass the error to the callback

```
return callback(err);
```

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, thank you very much for the explanations of what I was doing wrong. I've implemented the changes you suggested including error checking. This is all new to me so I'm still wrapping my head around it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Best is to understand how to use promises correctly, rather than converting them into callbacks.